# jQuery Ajax [object Object] error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with most types of inputs like checkboxes, selectors, file uploads and others. I want to post the form without page to refresh and here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var form = $('#form1111');
    var submit = $('#submit1111');

    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../ajax_comment.php',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: form.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                submit.val('Submitting...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
                $('.comment-block').append(item);
                form.trigger('reset');
                submit.val('Submit Comment').removeAttr('disabled');
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But I get an `[object Object]` in an `alert` after pressing the submit button. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The `error` handler is being hit which means there is an error in your server side code. To debug it properly, retrieve all the parameters passed to `error` and show them in the console: `error: function(xhr, error, status) { console.log(xhr, status, error); }`

Comment: to know what is the error, replace the alert with this: alert(JSON.stringify(e). So that you are able to know what is the error is.

Comment: if you know the error can you tell error message or what you want

Comment: As @Nishad K Ahamed  is saying first check Object Value you can check it by console by using console.log(e) that is easy for solving your problem .